# Ошибка чтения кодировки в среде windows PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Есть код приложения kivy. При запуски кода на Ubuntu IDE PyCharm выполняется без проблем. При переносе этого же кода в виндовс PyCharm выдает ошибку

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
>   14043: character maps to

Фаил закодирован в utf-8. Тоже самое происходит если код переносить из винды в ubuntu. Чтение файла с помощью примочек encoding='utf-8' не подходит особенность построения kivy приложений. Пересохранить и перезаписать в разных кодировках тоже не помогает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591955/355827 посмотрите этот ответ, может поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Избежать при помощи настроик PyCharm не получилось пришлось применить

```
with open(kv_file, encoding='utf-8') as kv:
    Builder.load_string(kv.read())
```

kv_file - путь к kv