# Вопрос по python и csv

Tags: python, парсер, csv, beautiful-soup

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

def get_html(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r.text
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Ошибка в функции get_html()', ex)


def write_csv(data):
    with open('chip_dip.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow((data['name'],
                         data['path'],
                         data['quantity1'],
                         data['price1'],
                         data['quantity2'],
                         data['price2'],
                         data['quantity3'],
                         data['price3'],
                         data['descriptions'],
                         data['params'],
                         data['documentation_href'],
                         data['documentation_description'],
                         data['item_number'],
                         data['artikul'],
                         data['part_number'],
                         data['brand'],
                         data['full_jpeg'],
                         data['small_jpeg'],
                         data['url']))


def get_data(url, path):
    html = get_html(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    try:
        product_name = soup.find('div', class_='main-header').find('h1').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        product_name = ''

    try:
        quantity1 = soup.find('div', class_='product__extrainfo-row').find('span').find('b').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        quantity1 = ''

    try:
        price1 = soup.find('span', class_='ordering__value').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        price1 = ''

    try:
        quantity2 = soup.find('div', class_='ordering__discount nw').find('b').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        quantity2 = ''

    try:
        price2 = soup.find('div', class_='ordering__discount nw').find('span', class_='price').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        price2 = ''

    try:
        quantity3 = soup.find_all('div', class_='ordering__discount nw')[-1].find('b').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        quantity3 = ''

    try:
        price3 = soup.find_all('div', class_='ordering__discount nw')[-1].find('span', class_='price').text.strip()
    except Exception as ex:
        price3 = ''

    try:
        descriptions = soup.find('div', class_='showhide item_desc').text.strip()
        print(descriptions)
    except Exception as ex:
        descriptions = ''

    try:
        params = ''
        product_params = soup.find_all('div', class_='showhide')[1].find_all('tr')
        for item_params in product_params:
            name = item_params.find('td', class_='product__param-name').text.strip()
            description = item_params.find('td', class_='product__param-value').text.strip()
            param = f'{name} : {description} '
            params += param
    except Exception as ex:
        params = ''

    try:
        documentation_href = soup.find('div', class_='product__documentation ptext').find('a',
                                                                                          class_='link download__link with-pdfpreview').get(
            'href')
    except:
        documentation_href = ''

    try:
        documentation_description = soup.find('div', class_='product__documentation ptext').find('a',
                                                                                                 class_='link download__link with-pdfpreview').text.strip()
    except:
        documentation_description = ''

    try:
        item_numbers = soup.find('div', class_='product_main-ids ptext').find_all('div', class_='product_main-id')
        item_number = item_numbers[0].find_all('span')[-1].text.strip()
    except:
        item_number = ''

    try:
        artikuls = soup.find('div', class_='product_main-ids ptext').find_all('div', class_='product_main-id')
        artikul = artikuls[1].find('span', itemprop='model').text.strip()
    except:
        artikul = ''

    try:
        part_numbers = soup.find_all('div', class_='product_main-id')
        part_number = part_numbers[2].find('span', itemprop='mpn').text
    except:
        part_number = ''

    try:
        brand = soup.find('div', class_='product_main-ids ptext').find('a', itemprop='brand').text.strip()
    except:
        brand = ''

    try:
        full_jpeg = soup.find_all('span', class_='galery')[0].find('img').get('src')
    except:
        full_jpeg = ''

    try:
        small_jpeg = soup.find_all('span', class_='galery')[1].find('img').get('src')
    except:
        small_jpeg = ''

    data = {'name': product_name,
            'path': path,
            'quantity1': quantity1,
            'price1': price1,
            'quantity2': quantity2,
            'price2': price2,
            'quantity3': quantity3,
            'price3': price3,
            'descriptions': descriptions,
            'params': params,
            'documentation_href': documentation_href,
            'documentation_description': documentation_description,
            'item_number': item_number,
            'artikul': artikul,
            'part_number': part_number,
            'brand': brand,
            'full_jpeg': full_jpeg,
            'small_jpeg': small_jpeg,
            'url': url}

    write_csv(data)


def get_block_url(block_name, catalog_header, category_name, item_url):
    for page in range(1, 1001):
        url = item_url + f'?page={page}'

        html = get_html(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        blocks = soup.find_all('tr', class_='with-hover')

        if len(blocks) > 0:
            for block in blocks:
                product_url = 'https://www.chipdip.ru' + block.find('td', class_='h_name').find('a',
                                                                                                class_='link').get(
                    'href')
                product_avtor = block.find('div', class_='nw').find('span').text.strip()
                product_path = f'{block_name}/{catalog_header}/{category_name}/{product_avtor}/'
                get_data(product_url, product_path)
        else:
            break


def get_categories_urls(block_name, url):
    html = get_html(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='catalog__g1 clear')

    for item in items:
        catalog_header = item.find('div', class_='catalog__header').find('a',
                                                                         class_='link link_dark like-header like-header_3').text.strip()
        catalog_items = item.find_all('li', class_='catalog__item')
        for catalog_item in catalog_items:
            category_url = 'https://www.chipdip.ru' + catalog_item.find('a', class_='link').get('href')
            category_name = catalog_item.find('a', class_='link').text.strip()
            get_block_url(block_name, catalog_header, category_name, category_url)


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    blocks = soup.find('ul', class_='cat-menu').find_all('li')
    for block in blocks:
        block_url = 'https://www.chipdip.ru' + block.find('a').get('href')
        block_name = block.find('a').text.strip()
        get_categories_urls(block_name, block_url)


def main():
    url = 'https://www.chipdip.ru'
    get_content(get_html(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

При записи в csv файл выходит ошибка **UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 935: character maps to** . Нашел решение: написать так with open('chip_dip.csv', 'a', **encoding="utf-8"**) as f:
Но если так сделать, то ошибка не появляется, но зато искажается текст в csv файле, появляются какие то непонятные символы.Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

С решением `with open('chip_dip.csv', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:` все хорошо, проверьте, чтобы в прогремме, которой вы открываете .csv файл указанна кодировка utf-8.

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Excel так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Тут описанно как решать](https://www.webtoffee.com/how-to-save-csv-excel-file-as-utf-8-encoded/#what-is-utf-8-encoding)

И, конечно, при работе надо октрывать файл с учетом того, что он utf-8, обычно все хорошо, но если какие-то проблемы, тот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33868/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python-readline-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-utf-8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-charmap) есть решение

Comment: большое вам спасибо, значит нужно в программе указать кодировку utf-8. Можете еще подсказать, почему последняя ссылка выводится не в отдельную колонку? Может можно это как то исправить

Comment: Вроде в отдельную, я просто в Excel не разворачивала колонки. Сам файл выглядит так. Первая строка: ...https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/792/DOC002792006.jpg;https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/991/DOC003991614.jpg;https://www.chipdip.ru/product/fscq0765rtydtu-2 Как видите ссылки разделенны ; Т.ч. все в отдельных колонках