# Определение charmap ошибки в строке

Tags: python

Есть код где при выполнение его нужно записать строку в сsv. Но проблема в том что в строках время от времени появляется charmap ошибка. решил проблему условно таким образом:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
text = "(Словакия, Kriváň)"
x = []
try:
    print(text)
except:
    for i in text:
        try:
            print(i)
            x.append(i)
        except:
            x.append("#")
print(x)
x = ''.join(x)
print(x)
```

Но только в этом случае сильно засоряется терминал. Можно ли как то еще щупать без принта? или может есть какой то еще способ? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А это не помогает? <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/33868/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-python-readline-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-utf-8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-charmap>

Comment: А в какой момент ошибка появляется? Если в экселе, то там другая кодировка, не такая, как в терминале, непонятно, чем вам такой метод поможет.

Comment: Там просто эта строка получается селениумом терез текст класса. И когда я его получаю в строке и пытаюсь записать в csv выдает ошибку 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 85-86: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: А чем вы его записываете в `csv`? Может где-то там кодировку и указать.